# how to change sizes of button on other activity?

Tags: java, android-studio, button, android-activity

I have two different activity(main and settings) and in settings activity i have 4 different button. There are for change sizes and pozition of button in main activity. I don't find any documentation about it. How to change pozition and sizes of button in other activity.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: https://github.com/AgeDim/Clicker

Comment: No, show your code within the question, not as a link. And if your code is too long then [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to store selected value and then to set size with value from Shared Preferences

```
//To save
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(/*"your name for preferences"*/, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("BTN_SIZE", /*integer with selected value(e.g. selectedSize)*/);
editor.commit();// Or editor.apply();

//To retrieve
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(/*"same name for Prefs to call it"*/, 0);
int size = settings.getInt("BTN_SIZE", 0); //0 is the default value
```

Hope it helps!